# Mupdf Error when extracting pdf in Portable Xepersian

Tags: templates, xepersian

I am trying to compile this Springer paper template in a portable Xepersian.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ‎file template.tex‎ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% ‎This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3‎
% ‎for Springer journals‎.          ‎Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16‎
%
% ‎Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis‎
% ‎for your article‎. ‎Delete % signs as needed‎.
%
% ‎This template includes a few options for different layouts and‎
% ‎content for various journals‎. ‎Please consult a previous issue of‎
% ‎your journal as needed‎.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% ‎First comes an example EPS file‎ -- ‎just ignore it and‎
% ‎proceed on the \documentclass line‎
% ‎your LaTeX will extract the file if required‎
‎\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}‎
‎%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0‎
%%BoundingBox: ‎19 19 221 221‎
%%CreationDate: ‎Mon Sep 29 1997‎
%%Creator: ‎programmed by hand (JK)‎
‎%%EndComments‎
‎gsave‎
‎newpath‎
  ‎20 20 moveto‎
  ‎20 220 lineto‎
  ‎220 220 lineto‎
  ‎220 20 lineto‎
‎closepath‎
‎2 setlinewidth‎
‎gsave‎
  .‎4 setgray fill‎
‎grestore‎
‎stroke‎
‎grestore‎
‎\end{filecontents*}‎
%
‎\RequirePackage{fix-cm}‎
%
‎%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)‎
‎%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)‎
‎\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)‎
‎%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn‎
%
‎\smartqed  % flush right qed marks‎, ‎e.g‎. ‎at end of proof‎
%
‎\usepackage{graphicx}‎
%
‎%‎\usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system‎
%
% ‎insert here the call for the packages your document requires‎
‎%\usepackage{latexsym}‎
% ‎etc‎.
%
% ‎please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but‎
% ‎\newcommand{}{}‎
%
% ‎Insert the name of‎ "‎your journal‎" ‎with‎
% ‎\journalname{myjournal}‎
%
‎\begin{document}‎

‎\title{Insert your title here%\thanks{Grants or other notes‎
‎%about the article that should go on the front page should be‎
‎%placed here‎. ‎General acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the article.}‎
}
‎\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so‎, ‎write it here}‎

‎%\titlerunning{Short form of title}        % if too long for running head‎

‎\author{First Author         \and‎
        ‎Second Author‎ %etc.
}

‎%\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head‎

‎\institute{F‎. ‎Author \at‎
              ‎first address \\‎
              ‎Tel.‎: +‎123-45-678910\\‎
              ‎Fax‎: +‎123-45-678910\\‎
              ‎\email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\‎
%             ‎\emph{Present address:} of F‎. ‎Author  %  if needed‎
           ‎\and‎
           ‎S‎. ‎Author \at‎
              ‎second address‎
}

‎\date{Received‎: ‎date‎ / ‎Accepted‎: ‎date}‎
% ‎The correct dates will be entered by the editor‎


‎\maketitle‎

‎\begin{abstract}‎
‎Insert your abstract here‎. ‎Include keywords‎, ‎PACS and mathematical‎
‎subject classification numbers as needed‎.
‎\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}‎
% ‎\PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}‎
% ‎\subclass{MSC code1 \and MSC code2 \and more}‎
‎\end{abstract}‎

‎\section{Introduction}‎
‎\label{intro}‎
‎Your text comes here‎. ‎Separate text sections with‎
‎\section{Section title}‎
‎\label{sec:1}‎
‎Text with citations \cite{RefB} and \cite{RefJ}‎.
‎\subsection{Subsection title}‎
‎\label{sec:2}‎
‎as required‎. ‎Don't forget to give each section‎
‎and subsection a unique label (see Sect.~\ref{sec:1})‎.
‎\paragraph{Paragraph headings} Use paragraph headings as needed‎.
‎\begin{equation}‎
‎a^2+b^2=c^2‎
‎\end{equation}‎

% ‎For one-column wide figures use‎
‎\begin{figure}‎
% ‎Use the relevant command to insert your figure file‎.
% ‎For example‎, ‎with the graphicx package use‎
  ‎\includegraphics{example.eps}‎
% ‎figure caption is below the figure‎
‎\caption{Please write your figure caption here}‎
‎\label{fig:1}       % Give a unique label‎
‎\end{figure}‎
%
% ‎For two-column wide figures use‎
‎\begin{figure*}‎
% ‎Use the relevant command to insert your figure file‎.
% ‎For example‎, ‎with the graphicx package use‎
  ‎\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example.eps}‎
% ‎figure caption is below the figure‎
‎\caption{Please write your figure caption here}‎
‎\label{fig:2}       % Give a unique label‎
‎\end{figure*}‎
%
% ‎For tables use‎
‎\begin{table}‎
% ‎table caption is above the table‎
‎\caption{Please write your table caption here}‎
‎\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label‎
% ‎For LaTeX tables use‎
‎\begin{tabular}{lll}‎
‎\hline\noalign{\smallskip}‎
‎first & second & third  \\‎
‎\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}‎
‎number & number & number \\‎
‎number & number & number \\‎
‎\noalign{\smallskip}\hline‎
‎\end{tabular}‎
‎\end{table}‎


‎%\begin{acknowledgements}‎
‎%If you'd like to thank anyone‎, ‎place your comments here‎
‎%and remove the percent signs‎.
‎%\end{acknowledgements}‎

% ‎BibTeX users please use one of‎
‎%\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style‎, ‎author-year citations‎
‎%\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences‎
‎%\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics‎
‎%\bibliography{}   % name your BibTeX data base‎

% ‎Non-BibTeX users please use‎
‎\begin{thebibliography}{}‎
%
% ‎and use \bibitem to create references‎. ‎Consult the Instructions‎
% ‎for authors for reference list style‎.
%
‎\bibitem{RefJ}‎
% ‎Format for Journal Reference‎
‎Author‎, ‎Article title‎, ‎Journal‎, ‎Volume‎, ‎page numbers (year)‎
% ‎Format for books‎
‎\bibitem{RefB}‎
‎Author‎, ‎Book title‎, ‎page numbers‎. ‎Publisher‎, ‎place (year)‎
% ‎etc‎
‎\end{thebibliography}‎

‎\end{document}‎
% ‎end of file template.tex‎
```

But After doing so it gives me the following error which I really dont understand what to do with:

> +mupdf\fitz\stm_open.c:112: fz_openrfile(): syserr: open 'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Test\Springer.pdf': No0êf3Ðò7 | mupdf\mupdf\pdf_open.c:699: pdf_loadxref(): cannot open file: 'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Test\Springer.pdPêf3ðò7 + mupdf\fitz\stm_open.c:112: fz_openrfile(): syserr: open 'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Test\Springer.pdf': Noàéf3ò7 | mupdf\mupdf\pdf_repair.c:165: pdf_repairxref(): cannot open file 'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Test\Springer

Please help me.

Comment: Your code is plenty of the invisible character `U+200E`. Delete them with the help of your editor.

Comment: What text editor are you using? My impression is that it's one tailored for right-to-left writing systems and so it inserts an invisible LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK (U+200E) when you insert a Latin letter. This is the most probable cause of your problems.

Comment: @egreg Close or answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Done.

Answer (score 2):

Your editor inserts many invisible LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK (U+200E) characters in the input, that confuse LaTeX.

Probably the editor is tailored for right-to-left writing.

You can solve the issue by adding the line

```
\catcode"E2=9 \catcode"80=9 \catcode"8E=9
```

at the very start of the file, but ensuring no U+200E is inserted at the beginning.

However, the best is to remove all those characters from the input file.